# Can mechas fly in Robocraft?

Tags: robocraft

I have recently made a mecha in Robocraft, and I am curious: can a mecha fly?  I am using a mk7 mecha leg, so it is quite heavy.  Could I use wings, or helicopter blades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can make it "fly". You can use anything you like to produce the lift, helium may be useful in lightening your robot and you can use aerofoils, hover blades or even only helium and thrusters. Any of the equipment that will produce lift can make your mecha fly.

Since you have legs as well, I'm assuming that you want it to be able to walk around on the ground as well. For this scenario it's likely that the hover blades would suit your needs reasonably well. You will still likely need several helium blocks as well to lighten your vehicle (but not too many that it's semi-buoyant when walking around.

The problem with your design is that it's going to be incredibly difficult to balance the weight in order to create a flying vehicle. Whatever you design will likely be incredibly unstable and unmaneuverable. Not to mention that to make a "dual" vehicle you will be using up extra ranking points and your end result will be a higher tier vehicle; ie. it will be weaker than a vehicle that could only walk or only fly.

Comment: Great... i feel like noob!

Comment: Trial and error.  Don't need to do things perfectly in one go.

Comment: I know this tutorial is outdated now, but all the parts needed still exist in the current version. If you want a bot that walks and flies effectively, try the [T7 Scarab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X79yXWsP0Xc). I modified this design to have protective layers of blocks underneath the rudders and wings, also providing places to mount weapons. You can lighten the bot by replacing the blocks underneath the wings that aren't mounted by weapons with aero-rods, and you might consider using plasma instead of nano healers if you want a decent bomber.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you can add that as your own answer

Comment: Well, not really. It's not how to make a mecha fly, because it uses the other type of walker legs.